# Google+ Activity List How to Sorted Published Date Wise in Python?

Tags: python, google-plus

Google Plus Activity List How to Sorting Published date wise.
I am Get The JSON data Form Below Code

```
SERVICE = build('plus', 'v1')
activity = SERVICE.activities().list(userId=wall.auth_user, collection='public')
```

but I am This data How to Sorting by publish date.

Thank You,

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: Activities are already sorted by newest first. Please be more specific about what you are trying to accomplish, what you have tried, and how it didn't work.